# Any payment gateway for ios That Provide credit and debit card scan functionalities

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, payment

i want implement credit and debit card Scan functionalities in my app

Answer (score -1):

Card.io can be used to scan credit and debit card.
https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK

Comment: You can check this link. Card.io can scan debit cards also but embedded one. https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/issues/166